# How to call a function on html event with context?

Tags: javascript

I want to access event properties in a js function which is called on html onkeypress event.

HTML code

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" onkeypress='keypress_event()'>
```

Javascript

```
function keypress_event(event)
{
    console.log(event.charCode);
}
```

Comment: Then pass `event` to the function?

Comment: Of course, you shouldn't be using inline event handler attributes in the first place.

Comment: I don't know how to pass event to it. I have tried passing this context but it did not work!

Comment: Use `window.event.charCode` in function

Comment: @Mihir— *window.event* is not supported by a large percentage of browsers in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use THis

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" onkeypress='keypress_event(event)'>


function keypress_event(event)
{
    console.log(event.charCode);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/scdLph03/)

Comment: Sorry to say but it's not working for me :-( in console screen it says undefined!

Comment: It is working now actually i was passing this parameter instead of event i correct that and it is done!

Thanks man!